# Is there a way to "capture" html code of a print process?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

is there a way to capture the html code of a printable page ?
For example, i click on a button for print a page that is dynamically created.
It's open the preview page to print, with the possibility to select a printer.
At this point, is it possible read the html code of the page ?
How ?

Comment: Wouldn't the code be the same as before the printing

Comment: i don't know the code, it's a template that i can print.